# Angular.js - controller not executing for index, works for the rest of templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, ngroute

I have this weird problem - i use Angular's ngRoute for my application.
I have different controllers for the templates, such as:

routes.js:

```
angular.module('PokeApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/template-index.html',
      controller: 'IndexController'
    })
    .when('/products', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/template-products.html',
      controller: 'ProductsController'
    })
    .when('/events', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/template-events.html',
      controller: 'EventsController'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

controllers are included in the index.html as follows:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/routes.js"></script>

<script src="js/controllers/controller-index.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controller-products.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/controller-events.js"></script>
```

my controllers are practically the same - ill show you index and products for example:

controller-index.js:

```
angular.module('PokeApp')
.controller('IndexController', function($scope) {
  // for testing purposes
  console.log("hi");

  ..

});
```

controller-products.js:

```
angular.module('PokeApp')
.controller('ProductsController', function($scope) {
  // again, for testing
  console.log("hi");

  ..

});
```

but here's the weird part - when i get to the '/' page, i don't get the controller log to the console. there is no typo, since if i change the name of the controller for a wrong one, i get the error in the console.

but when i go to the /products, i get the 'hi' as expected.

i checked everything i can think of - typos, wrong locations, threads of stackoverflow. i just cant figure out why the index controller refuses to work, while the others (i have a few more) work as expected.

can anyone help me figure this out? thanks for your time.

Comment: Look in browser dev tools network to see if template request is failing.

Comment: file is being received successfully, i checked there

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add an otherwise case to your route provider:

      `otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });`

Comment: ye, i forgot to show that part here, but the .otherwise is there in my file

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the default route like this

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/index', {
        templateUrl: '../templates/template-index.html',
        controller: 'IndexController',
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/index' });
```

---

But I recommend you to use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/tree/legacy) from starts of your project.
It supports everything the normal ngRoute can do as well as many extra functions.

Comment: ye, i forgot to show that part here, but the .otherwise is there in my file.
i will check the UI-Router though, thanks!